# splicing strings

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to see if there is a good way to populate a dictionary with the following text scenarios:

```
(1) The company owns the target.
(2) The accounts are: (a) true and fair; (b) not misleading.
(3) The company is not a party to any litigation.
```

(1) and (3) are easy enough to split out - but (2) is the point I am struggling with.  Ideally it would read "The accounts are true and fair" / "The accounts are not misleading", which requires a bit of splicing and then recombining strings.

I came up with the below but I don't think it is straight forward and am sure there is a better answer...

```
w = "(1) The accounts are:\n (a) true and fair;\n (b) not misleading."
x = re.findall('^[(].[)](.+)[:]', w)
y = re.findall('[(a-z)]\s(.+)[;]', w)
z = re.findall('[(a-z)]\s(.+)[.]', w)
print(x + y)
print(x + z)
```

Comment: are you saying they need to be "true and fair" AND "not misleading" or "true and fair" OR "not misleading"?

Comment: Also you don't really explain what makes and account "true and fair" or "misleading"

Comment: @Kevin I think those questions are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @JayDee are you saying that the code you have shown produces the output you want? I don't think there is a much more straightforward way to write this code.

Comment: If the text is always like that, why you need to match anything? I suppose the input text can vary, or is this really all it can be? For instance, can it be "(5) The accounts are not misleading"?

Comment: What about "(5) The accounts are: (a) not misleading" or "(5) The accounts are: (a) true and fair", ... are those all possible inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
import re
s ="(1) The accounts are:\n (a) true and fair;\n (b) not misleading."
match =re.findall(r' [\w\s]+',h)
match
# -> [' The accounts are', ' true and fair', ' not misleading']

match = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(),match))
match
# -> ['The accounts are', 'true and fair', 'not misleading']

x = ' '.join([match[0], match[1]])
y = ' '.join([match[0], match[2]])
x,y
# -> ('The accounts are true and fair', 'The accounts are not misleading')
```

Comment: BTW, `list(map(lambda))` is harder to read than a list comprehension: `[x.strip() for x in match]`

Comment: Also, it would help to add an explanation, not just code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to match also when only one of the two "options" appears in the text, i.e. only "true and fair" or only "not misleading"...

One issue in your regex is that `[(a-z)]` does not do what you think it does. Such a class only matches one single character. So what you wanted there is this: `\([a-z]\)`.

Here is how you could make it work:

```
w = "(1) The accounts are:\n (a) true and fair;\n (b) not misleading."
res = re.findall(r"\(\d\)\s(.*):$\s*\([a-z]\)(.*?)(?:\.|;$\s*\([a-z]\)(.*?)\.)$", w, re.MULTILINE)

for a, b, c in res:
    print(a + b)
    if c:
        print(a + c)
```